# How to Move A Ruby On Rails Website To New Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server-migration

I have a Ruby on Rails website which I have successfully tar the apps directory which included the current folder ect. Which I Wget to transfer the files over. The server I have moved to is setup to run Ruby on Rails but is there anything else I need todo to get it running?

Any commands via SSH?

**My new server setups is Ubuntu 11.04 running ISPConfig 3 as the server admin.**

Current the file are in the correct location with the correct permissions and owners. But all I'm getting is the default ISPConfig page.

*(This is the default index page of your website.
This file may be deleted or overwritten without any difficulty. This is produced by the file index.html in the web directory.)*

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using (Apache, NGinx, etc), what web service is running your site (Passenger, Tomcat, etc), what flavor of ruby are you using (MRI, JRuby, etc)?  Have you tried to configure these at all?

Comment: The Http Sever is Apache and we are using Passenger. Running Ruby on Rails. The site used to run on the server in question and have kept it whilst trying out a new server..  It usually the job of my dev which ive lost contact with.

Comment: Was basic configuration done already - does your apache config contain a virtual host entry for port 80 pointing to your rails public directory? See http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger.mov for simple instructions or http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html for all the details

Comment: Yes i ran cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and the vHost file is there for the domain as show in the video.

Comment: Rails `3.0.9` is five years old. For [security reasons](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12043/product_id-22568/Rubyonrails-Ruby-On-Rails.html) you might want to consider upgrading the app to a version that is still maintained and gets security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a symbolic link on the server to the application something like

```
cd ~/public_html;
ln -s ~/rails-test-application/public rails3
```

http://www.site5.com/blog/programming/ruby-rails/how-to-deploy-phusion-passenger-to-a-subdirectory-routing-errors-and-restarting/20090414/